# Vuejs app in docker exposing ports does not work

Tags: docker, vue.js

I have simple vue.js app, here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run generate

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

I run it using:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 frontend-name:0.1
```

but it does not work then. if I will run it using --net=host it works fine.
the same issue if I try using docker-compose with port mapping.

what can be the issue ?

Comment: Speculating: the application binds to 127.0.0.1, the container-private localhost address, instead of 0.0.0.0, "all interfaces".  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve], including enough application source code to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Having same issue , although changing expose port in the Dockefiler and changed docker-compose the ports - it doesnt work